# How to fix "Network Error" using react native, expo, expressjs, and mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, mongoose

I am currently working on a calorie tracking app for learning purposes. Right now I am trying to connect my React Native frontend to my backend using axios, however I am getting the following error:

```
Network Error
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:null in dispatchEvent
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I have looked through quite a few threads on stackoverflow and GitHub relating to this issue, but they all resulted in the same error. I have verified that the address axios is trying to access works on postman.

This is the code, right now I am using React Native's Expo to create my app.

From the frontend

```
  const addMeal = async (name, foodItems) => {
    return await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/meals", {
        title: name,
        foodItems: foodItems,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        hideModal();
        setMealName("");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

From the backend

```
import express from "express";
import { PORT, mongDBURL } from "./config.js";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Meal } from "./models/mealModels.js";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ status: "Started" });
});

// PORT = 5000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.post("/meals", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newMeal = {
      title: req.body.title,
      foodItems: req.body.foodItems,
    };
    const meal = await Meal.create(newMeal);
    console.log("Successful");
    return res.status(201).send(meal);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
});

mongoose
  .connect(mongDBURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Replace localhost with your systems ipaddress

Comment: @AlokPrakash tried to do that, resulted in the same error or the following new error:

timeout exceeded
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:null in handleTimeout
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:null in dispatchEvent
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to expose a port on your Android device to a port on your computer.

Since you are running your backend on 5000 port try to bellow command see if it works

```
adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5000
```

Comment: I am running my react native app through the Expo Go app on IOS. Do you have any idea how I would be able to do what you recommended for my situation?